# Nullpointer exception when trying to insert parsed data into database

Tags: android, database, android-asynctask, nullpointerexception

i am parsing the json data , and trying to put that data into the database, i took the instance of my dbadapter in my DownloadJson class and passing the values, but its giving nullpointer exception.below is my code

```
public class DownloadJSON extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    public static final String UNIVERSITY_NAMES = "name";
    public static final String UNIVERSITY_URL = "url";


    private static MyDBAdapter dbHelper;

    String fileName = "json.txt";


    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> arraylist;

    private Context context;




        public DownloadJSON(Context context){
            this.context = context;
        }


    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        //startWebServiceForExcelData();
         readFileFromAssets(fileName,context);
        return null;

}

public static String readFileFromAssets(String fileName, Context context) {
     AssetManager assetManager = context.getAssets();
     InputStream is = null;
        try {
            is = assetManager.open(fileName);

            int size = is.available();
            byte[] buffer = new byte[size];
            is.read(buffer);
            is.close();
            String text = new String(buffer);
System.out.println("tex===========t"+ text);

parseJson(text);
            return text;

        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);}}

private static void parseJson(String text) {

     ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> contactList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
     try {
         JSONObject mainObject = new JSONObject(text);
         JSONObject uniObject = mainObject.getJSONObject("university");
         String  uniName = uniObject.getString(UNIVERSITY_NAMES);
         String uniURL = uniObject.getString(UNIVERSITY_URL);

         System.out.println("uniName============="+uniName);
         System.out.println("uniURL============="+uniURL);

         dbHelper.saveCategoryRecord(new University(uniName,uniURL));// showing  error at this line

         HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
         // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
         map.put(UNIVERSITY_NAMES, uniName);
         map.put(UNIVERSITY_URL, uniURL);       
         // adding HashList to ArrayList
         contactList.add(map);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }}}
```

Belos is my methos in my database adapter

```
  public void saveCategoryRecord(University university) {

        String query = "insert into"+ SQLITE_TABLE2 + "values ( ?, ?,)";
                SQLiteStatement stmt = mDb.compileStatement(query);// error at this line
                stmt.bindString(1, university.getName());
                stmt.bindString(2, university.getUrl());
                stmt.execute();
                System.out.println("bindString=========="+ stmt);
    }
```

Below is my log trace

```
   09-24 13:23:52.875: E/AndroidRuntime(30727): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
09-24 13:23:52.875: E/AndroidRuntime(30727):    at com.markupartist.android.actionbar.example.MyDBAdapter.saveCategoryRecord(MyDBAdapter.java:206)
09-24 13:23:52.875: E/AndroidRuntime(30727):    at com.markupartist.android.actionbar.example.DownloadJSON.parseJson(DownloadJSON.java:124)
09-24 13:23:52.875: E/AndroidRuntime(30727):    at com.markupartist.android.actionbar.example.DownloadJSON.readFileFromAssets(DownloadJSON.java:101)
09-24 13:23:52.875: E/AndroidRuntime(30727):    at com.markupartist.android.actionbar.example.DownloadJSON.doInBackground(DownloadJSON.java:42)
09-24 13:23:52.875: E/AndroidRuntime(30727):    at com.markupartist.android.actionbar.example.DownloadJSON.doInBackground(DownloadJSON.java:1)
09-24 13:23:52.875: E/AndroidRuntime(30727):    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
09-24 13:23:52.875: E/AndroidRuntime(30727):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
09-24 13:23:52.875: E/AndroidRuntime(30727):    ... 5 more
```

where i am doing wrong?

Comment: What is your json response ?

Comment: I forgot to initialise the dbadapter, now i did itz working ..thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forget to initialize your database adapter class and you are directly using it in your `parseJson()` method.

Initialize your database adapter as below in your constructor.​

```
public DownloadJSON(Context context){
    this.context = context;
    dbHelper=new MyDBAdapter();
}
```

**EDIT:**

In your `saveCategoryName()` method there is extra comma in your query just remove the last `,` from query and write it as below:

```
String query = "insert into"+ SQLITE_TABLE2 + "values ( ?,?)";
```

Comment: Hi i did now i am getting error in saveCategoryRecord() method

Comment: @GrlsHu  hi updated removing that coma, but still its giving null pointer exception at line SQLiteStatement stmt = mDb.compileStatement(query);

Comment: What is your `mDb` contains ? It might be possible that you have not initialized `mDb` database instance.

Comment: @GrlsHu  ..you are right, i initialized with  my dbhelper.open()..thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

dbHelper is never initialized. You should have `dbHelper = new MyDBAdapter(...)` or something similar somewhere...

Comment: Exactly..you are right...i initialised dbHelper = new MyDBAdapter(context);  its working

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure context is not null here

```
AssetManager assetManager = context.getAssets();
```

Handle a top level exception along with JSONException and IOException

```
 } catch (JSONException e) {

 } catch (IOException e) {
```

Moreover, you need to handle the exception that could be thrown by this method:

```
readFileFromAssets(fileName,context);
```

I hope this helps, feel free to ask more questions.